# OpenCV VideoCapture can't access certain device index

Tags: python, opencv, camera, usb

I want to take a series of Images in python with different webcams, stack them and afterwards save them in different folders counted from 1 to 14 for each camera. Stacking is a process by which each pixel of different pictures get summed up and by the end divided by the number of pictures.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from time import strftime, localtime, gmtime
import subprocess
import sys
import glob


def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])


install("opencv-python")
import cv2


###################### Camport Access #####################################################################################


def list_ports():
# Test the ports and returns a tuple with the available ports and the ones that are working.

is_working = True
dev_port = 0
working_ports = []
available_ports = []
while is_working:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(dev_port)
    if not camera.isOpened():
        is_working = False
        print("Port %s is not working." % dev_port)
    else:
        is_reading, img = camera.read()
        w = camera.get(3)
        h = camera.get(4)
        if is_reading:
            print("Port %s is working and reads images (%s x %s)" % (dev_port, h, w))
            working_ports.append(dev_port)
        else:
            print("Port %s for camera ( %s x %s) is present but does not reads." % (dev_port, h, w))
            available_ports.append(dev_port)
    dev_port += 1
return available_ports, working_ports


available, camports = list_ports()
print(camports)


picture_count = 5
hours = int(input("amount of hours: "))
minute = localtime().tm_min

for i in range(stunden):

     hour = localtime().tm_hour
     print("starting hour: ", i)

     for j in camports:
         cam_port = j
         print("currently taking images at camport: ", j + 1)
         cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_port, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
         # take picture here and safe it
         Images = []
         timestr = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H_%M_%S")

         for k in range(picture_count):
             cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0)
             time.sleep(0.5)
             result, image = cam.read()
             if result:
                 Images.append(image)
                 img_sum = np.zeros(np.shape(image))  # Sum of images
                 img_cnt = np.full(image.shape, picture_count)

                 for img in Images:
                     img_sum = img_sum + img.astype(float)  # Sum images
                 avg_img = img_sum / img_cnt  # Divide sum by count, for computing the average.
                 avg_img = np.round(avg_img).astype(np.uint8)  # Round an cast to uint8
             else:
                 print("failure at: ", j + 1, k + 1)

         cv2.imwrite(f"path\\{j + 1}\\pic {i + 1} {timestr}.tiff", avg_img)
     print("waiting for the next hour")

     while localtime().tm_min is not minute or localtime().tm_hour == hour:
       time.sleep(1)
```

I have a problem while accessing the cameras. Unattached to which camera I'm using the 4th, 6th, 8th, 10th, 12th and 14th camport won't work and give me the message that every picture made has failed. (see "failure at: ").
Do you have an idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have wrong indentations - edit question and put code with correct indentations because it can change everything.

Comment: maybe you should `release()` webcams in `list_ports()` and in main loop - before you use again `cv2.VideoCapture()`

Comment: code works for me if I remove `cv2.CAP_DSHOW` from `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_port, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` but I use Linux and I don't have `DirectShow`

Comment: how many cameras do you really have? or do you have image files? VideoCapture is not for reading picture files.

Comment: @furas thanks alot that was super helpful. I tried to `release()` it and it worked perfectly.